# NetWare Apache Module for Directory Redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, novell

I'm trying to find a modern version of modrdirs.nlm that was for Apache 1.3 on NetWare. Does this work on Apache 2.0/2.2? Is there an OES2 Linux equivalent modules?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

All of that is built into mod_edir, a single module that does everything modrdir and modhdir did. Last I checked, that was shipping with SP8. I believe the config semantics are very similar. I had some teething troubles with it when I upgraded to Apache2 when we upgraded to NW6.5, but as of SP8 it had been rock stable.

Some helpful links:

- Newer files: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-edir/files/
- Doc: http://www.novell.com/documentation/oes/web_apache/?page=/documentation/oes/web_apache/data/ajouk03.html